# using a variable in a whie loop outside the loop in php

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a variable inside a while loop i.e. `$confirm` This variable is dynamic and can be any list of different values.

I would want to use this variable outside the loop to use it to check whether it is equal a secondary variable

```
<?php 

$confirm = "";

while ($row_tutorunit = $tutorunit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $confirm .= $row_tutorunit["code"];
}

?>
```

Usage;

```
<?php if ($confirm !== "$anothervariable"); { echo 'style="display:none;"';  }  ?>
```

As i am using it, it does not seem to work

Comment: This is a really bad question. Are the two bits of code in the same file? What values *might* be in the database? What happens when you print out the values of $confirm and $anothervariable? Are you aware of the difference between no quotes, single quotes and double quotes in PHP?

Comment: Using the `$confirm` variable in a while loop has no bearing on whether or not you can use it outside the while loop. Based on the edit you just made, the problem appears to be an extra semicolon after your if condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($confirm !== $anotherVariable); { echo 'test'; }
//    I think your problem is here^
```

Basically what that stray semicolon does is to separate the `if` from the bracketed code that should be attached to it. In effect you are telling PHP

```
if ($confirm !== $anotherVariable) {
    ; // Do nothing
}
echo 'test'; // Always
```

Side note, (assuming `$anothervariable` is a string) `"$anothervariable"` is *exactly the same thing* as `$anothervariable`. The quotes are superfluous. However `'$anothervariable'` is *not* the same thing as `$anothervariable` because [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) works in double quoted strings, but not in single quoted strings.